# what are the semantics of datalog and prolog?

Tags: prolog, datalog

Does datalog operate on sets or multisets? Does the same apply to prolog as well? I wasn't able to find any documentations on that.

Comment: Prolog has predicates for handling multisets, if that is what you are asking (determined by Googling "prolog multiset").

Comment: Thanks @ScottHunter. Does that mean prolog operates on sets by default?

Comment: The primary data structure in Prolog is the *list*, which is often used like a set but both allows duplicates and respects order.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I think OP asked about the semantics of a predicate, say `p(1). p(2). p(1).` here the goal `p(X)` produces a sequences of answer substitutions, like `X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3.`

Comment: @false: Clearly you are better at reading questions than I; not seeing the word "predicate" anywhere kind of threw me.

Comment: @ScottHunter *list*  is **not** the primary data structure in Prolog. Just a type of compound term that is often misused and abused, specially by novice programmers.

Comment: @repeat: It should read `X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datalog's semantics is defined over finite sets.

Prolog, however, gives you  sequences of answer substitutions and in the case of Prolog with constraints answers. Answer substitutions may represent simply solutions, like in `X = 1`, but they may also represent infinitely many solutions, like in `X = [_A,_B,_C]`. The sequence of answer substitution can be seen as a multiset, but it is even a bit more general as the precise sequence matters. As in `X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 1`.

General answers with constraints extend the notion a bit further. An answer `X in 2..sup, X mod 2 #= 0` contains infinitely many solutions, it may also contain finitely many `X in 1..3`, or even none as in `X in 2..sup, X mod 2 #= 0, X mod 2 #= 1`.

Comment: Wiki mentions that Datalog on finite sets are guaranteed to terminate, but it doesn't say whether that finite set is the default?

Comment: @JRR: Many system extend the core, by, say arithmetics which itself permits to describe infinite sets.